# React Native, React-Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-stack

Can you help me on this problem:

> Failed to compile
> /home/coding/Документы/React-native/instagram/node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/module/views/Stack/CardStack.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-screens' in
> '/home/coding/Документы/React-native/instagram/node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/module/views/Stack'

This is source code:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import LandingScreen from "./components/auth/Landing";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Landing">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Landing"
          component={LandingScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based [official docs of react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project) you should install other related packages with the below command:

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

If you are using expo install these:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```